# How to create .jar in volly

Tags: android, jar, android-volley

I'm trying to setup server request using volly.now i have clone volly using `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley`.then i tried to create .jar inside the volly.i've used thees commands.

```
android update project -p .

ant jar
```

but it's display this error

```
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio and want to add Volley in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

> $ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley 
>   $ cd volley
>   $ android update project -p .
>   $ ant jar

and then you will get the jar file as follow position:

> bin/**volley.jar**

### Solution 2

Get the mirror from [here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

And then you can import the module to your **Android Studio Project**